# Get the output of sub jobs started with 'Start-Job' command of PowerShell

Tags: powershell, echo, start-job

I have a PowerShell script with the following code:

```
$functions = {
    Function test_function() 
    {
        echo "hello world"
    }
}

Function test_launcher()
{
    $EO = Start-Job -InitializationScript $functions -ScriptBlock {test_function} | Wait-Job
    $KK = Receive-Job -Job $EO
    echo $KK    }

test_launcher
```

But I don't know why the 'Hello world' string is not printed out. Does anyone knows how to modify this code in order to get the result of subjob 'test_function' printed on the screen?

Comment: Look at Receive-Job

Comment: Perfect. Thankyou

Comment: If you dont write an answer, I can not close this question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the jobs you start - look at `Receive-Job`